# How can I only reload a state with history.js if the user hits the back button?

Tags: jquery, history.js

I'm working on a form that is filled using AJAX requests. Once the form is submitted, search results are displayed. If the user hits the back button, the AJAX powered form is in its initial state with only the first select field.

I've added history.js so that it will remember the selections and reload them. Unfortunately, this also occurs when I come back to the page through an organic visit (entering the URL in the broswer). How can I detect if the browser's back button was used to get back to the search form?

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  History = window.History;
  StateData = History.getState().data;

  // ... stuff happens

  // at this point, there has to be a check so it doesn't execute this code
  // for organic visits
  for(var field in StateData) {
    // this is just a basic example
    if( StateData[field] == 'foo' ){
      $('#foo').click();
    }
    // there are more fields here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use popstate, e.g.:

```
 window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    var State = History.getState(); 
    console.log( 'State: ' + State );
 });
```

But I don't believe you're meant to be able to detect specifically whether the 'back' button was pressed - your page is meant to use State info the same way whether the Back or Forward buttons (or neither) were pressed.